# Kendo Grid not showing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid which works fine in Internet Explorer (10 and 11). However, it doesn't load at all in firefox(tested with latest version and a few previous versions as well).

In one JavaScript file, let's call it `fileA`, I have my ajax request call, and then I call a function from another file, (`fileB`) to pass in the JSON object from my request.

`fileA`:

```
//the json object retrieved from my ajax call:
var obj = {name: "John Doe"};

//call to fileB
Test(obj);
```

`fileB` takes the form of a closure:

```
 var Test = (function() {
 var myfunction = function(obj){
   showGrid(obj);
 }

 function showGrid(obj){
  var datasource;

  if(obj != null){
    datasource = new kendo.data.DataSouce({
       data: obj,
       pageSize:10
    });
  } else{
     datasource = new kendo.data.DataSouce({
       data: [];
    });
  }

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: datasource
        height: 850,
        groupable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
          refresh: true,
          pageSizes: true,
          buttonCount: 15
        },
        columns: [{
           field: "name",
           title: "Name",
           width: 200
         }]
       });
     }

})();
```

I've created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/savxdnt3/1/

Where did I go wrong with this, and how can I make this work in firefox? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- You have a lot of typos in your code. (kendo.data.DataSouce) missing r; obsolet semi-colon at `data: [];` etc
- you provide an obj as the data source, but Kendo expects an array.

Any way, here is one simple approach:

```
function showGrid(obj){
  var datasource;

  if(obj != null) {
    datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ // fixed spelling
       data: obj,
       pageSize:10
    });
  } else {
     datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ //fixed spelling
       data: [] //removed semi-colon
    });
  }

   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
     dataSource: datasource,
     height: 850,
     groupable: false,
     sortable: true,
     pageable: {
       refresh: true,
       pageSizes: true,
       buttonCount: 15
     },
     columns: [{
       field: "name",
       title: "Name",
       width: 200
     }]
   });
 }

 obj = [{name: "John Doe"}] // pass in array, not object;
showGrid(obj);
```

Here is an updated fiddle, using the revealing module pattern: http://jsfiddle.net/savxdnt3/2/

This should make things more readable. Put the grid stuff in one file and use it as `Test` (or rename it) in any other piece of code

Comment: Thanks for the help!